# ValueError: no results when using pd.apply()

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I have a column with genres of movies. n genres clumped together per movie into a single cell. I want to separate them into a list and ultimately compare the genres of a particular movie to the total list of all genres and have the total list of all genres be just 1s and 0s. 1 if the genre is in my particular movie and 0 if it isn't.

The pd.apply() function returns an error I can't seem to fix.
ValueError: no results

```py
list_of_genres = list(genre_df['genres'])
genre_array = []

my_movie = "xyz"


def map_genres():
    my_genre = movies_df.loc[movies_df['title'] == my_movie]['genres']
    my_genre = list(my_genre.str.split('|'))
    my_genre = sum(my_genre, [])

    for count in range(0, len(list_of_genres)):
        for count1 in range(0, len(my_genre)):
            if list_of_genres[count] == my_genre[count1]:
                list_of_genres[count] = 1
        if list_of_genres[count] != 1:
            list_of_genres[count] = 0

    return np.asarray(list_of_genres)

movies_df['genre_array'] = movies_df['genres'].apply(map_genres())
```

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. Please show an example of your dataframe

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to do. Try to include a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with a sample desired output. On the last line, it should be `.apply(map_genres)` without the parentheses. You should pass the function as an argument, not call it.